# pybind11 function/method arguments/doc string def order?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

What's the def order of pybind11 function/method arguments and doc-strings ?

For example I want to define a class method like this:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(my_module, m) {
  m.doc() = "my pybind11 module";
  py::class_<MyClass>(m, "MyClass")
    .def("my_method", &MyClass::my_method, py::arg("a"), py::arg("b"), "print a and b");
}
```

I want to define two args `a` and `b`, and doc-string "print a and b".

I'm pretty sure that first arg is python module API name, second arg is C++ function/method's pointer.

But I'm not sure what order should I write about function/method's arguments and doc-string:

- args first, then doc-string: `py::arg("a"), py::arg("b"), "print a and b"`
- doc-string first, then args: `"print a and b", py::arg("a"), py::arg("b")`

It seems that both could compile successfully.

Comment: Does this help? https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html#keyword-arguments

Comment: @kiner_shah, thanks, so doc-string first, then function args